# what is causing an index error in the model of this code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, deep-learning

Hi I was trying to creat a deep learning model using Tensorflow Keras and I recieved an index error.
The code:

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(train)

train=scaler.transform(train)
test=scaler.transform(test)

# Creating Deep Model


model = Sequential()

# Add an input layer
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu', input_shape=(211,)))

# Add one hidden layer
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))

# Add an output layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

#add improvements 
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#Train the model

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train,train_targets,epochs=20, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

I am getting this error at the last line:

> File "C:\Users\snow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 80, in standardize_input_data
>       if isinstance(data[0], list):
>   IndexError: list index out of range

what does this error mean and what could be causing it? thx

Comment: I think the error is in the input. Check if `train` object is a `np.array`and its shape :D

Comment: type(train) is numpy.ndarray and its shape is (80, 211)

Comment: What about the `train_targets`? Also, could you provide the full traceback?

Comment: How about: `model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu', input_shape=(train.reshape(-1,1)))` ?